# Comma before "before" and "after"

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have the following table:

```
Troy, apothecaries' and avoirdupois weights

        | - Troy                      | - Avoirdupois
        | - Apothecaries' before 1864 | - Apothecaries' after 1864
------- | --------- | --------------- | --------- | --------------
Quarter | n/a       | n/a             |  2 stones |  12.7 kg
Stone   | n/a       | n/a             | 14 pounds |  6.35 kg
Pound   | 12 ounces | 0.37 kg         | 16 ounces |  0.45 kg
Ounce   |           | 31.1 g          |           | 28.35 g
```

Thinking logically, there should be no comma before *before* and *before* after, but for some reason my intuition tells me the opposite. Is it really required/recommended for some reason?

Comment: No reason for a comma there

Comment: It's not a grammatical sentence either way, but only a fragment.  So it's hard to say if a comma actually belongs.  I think either communicates the meaning clearly.   I would prefer to write it with a comma, perhaps emphasizing the difference between the two columns.  Perfectly fine use for a column heading in either case.